# How to call a variable from a preload script in godot?

Tags: godot, gdscript

When I make a preload script in godot and put a variable in there, how do I call the variable in my other scripts?

Is there a special way to call the variable that I don't know or is there a better way to do it than preload scripts?

Answer (score 5):

If you are preloading a script, e.g. `const item = preload("res://scripts/item.gd")` it acts as a type. That is, you can declare variables as it, and make instances of it. The variables declared on the script exist on its instances:

```
const Item = preload("res://scripts/item.gd")
var my_item:Item

func _ready():
    my_item = Item.new()
    print(my_item.variable)
```

See [Custom variable types](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/scripting/gdscript/static_typing.html#custom-variable-types) and [Classes and nodes](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_styleguide.html#classes-and-nodes). *By the way, no, there are no static variables in Godot, see "static" on [Keywords](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html#keywords) table.*

*You could be preloading a scene instead of a script. In that case you get a [`PackedScene`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_packedscene.html), similar rules apply. But you would be using the [`instance`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_packedscene.html#class-packedscene-method-instance) method.*

Instead of doing this, I suggest to give a `class_name` to your script. Godot will recognize it and make it available everywhere. See [Register scripts as classes](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/scripting_continued.html#register-scripts-as-classes).

---

Please note that this is different from accessing a variable defined on another node in the scene tree. If you are trying to access a variable defined in the script of another node in the scene tree, the use [`get_node`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node.html#class-node-method-get-node) or similar to access the node, and then you can access the variable on it. See [Understanding node paths](http://kidscancode.org/godot_recipes/basics/getting_nodes/).

---

If you need a global variable, what you want is an <strike>"singleton"</strike> [autoload](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/singletons_autoload.html). You can set a scene to autoload in the "AutoLoad" tab in your project settings (select the scene path, give it a name, and click "Add"). They will be available on the scene tree regardless of the scene. *They persist changes of scene.*

Since autoloads are on the scene tree, you can use `get_node` to access them. The path will `"/root/"` followed by the name you gave it. For example:

```
onready var global_variables = get_node("/root/GlobalVariables")

func _ready():
    print(global_variables.variable)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have access to one script from 1 or more different scripts, It is not a good way to use preload script. (at least in my opinion)
I prefer to make an script, global in the project and have access to that script from other scripts and nodes.
Now how to do that?

1. Open a new or a prefered scene.
2. On top menu, under project scroll, click on Project Settings.
   [image: Godot Project Setting]
3. On Project Settings, click on Autoload tab and add the script that you want to have access to from everyscript in the game and ofcourse add a fine Node Name to it.
   [image: Godot Autoload]
4. Now based on that **Node Name**, you can have access to anything inside that global script.

For example, if this is my global script that I Autoloaded it as **Global** node name:

```
extends Node

var num: int = 5
```

I can have access to num variable from every other scripts like:

```
Global.num = 6
```

Make sure to take a look at the [AutoLoad Documentation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/singletons_autoload.html) for more info.